# Using correlated subquery and MAX

Tags: sql, max, correlated-subquery

I have two tables:

> **InventoryPart**:
>
> *PartNumber*, PartDescription, CategoryID, EOQ, StockPrice,
>   ReorderLevel, StockLevel, StockOnOrder, Weight

and

> **CustOrderLine**
>
> OrderID, *PartNumber*, UnitPrice, OrderQuantity, Discount, Status

I only need to return PartNumber, PartDescription, StockPrice, and CategoryID of the most expensive inventory part **in each category**

This is the best I have come up with so far...

```
SELECT IP.PartNumber, IP.PartDescription, IP.CategoryID, IP.StockPrice
FROM InventoryPart IP, CustOrderLine COL
WHERE IP.PartNumber = COL.PartNumber
AND COL.UnitPrice IN
  (SELECT MAX(COL.UnitPrice)
   FROM CustOrderLine COL)
```

The problem with this code is that it returns the MAX UnitPrice of ALL the categories, instead of separating by category

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours and I feel like I'm doing more harm than good now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sample data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work using a subquery to get your `MAX` UnitPrice associated with each CategoryId.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.*
FROM InventoryPart IP
   JOIN CustOrderLine COL ON IP.PartNumber = COL.PartNumber
   JOIN (
    SELECT IP.CategoryID, MAX(COL.UnitPrice) MaxPrice
    FROM InventoryPart IP INNER JOIN
        CustOrderLine COL ON IP.PartNumber = COL.PartNumber
    GROUP BY IP.CategoryID
   ) T ON IP.CategoryId = T.CategoryId AND COL.UnitPrice = T.MaxPrice
```

Here is a reduced [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d8bd/1) that shows the inventory parts with the highest unit price per category.

Good luck.

Comment: sgeddes, thank you so much for your help. I also want to thank you for introducing me to SQL Fiddle. Very nice tool!

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple version.

```
SELECT  a.PartNumber, a.PartDescription, a.CategoryID, a.StockPrice
FROM    InventoryPart a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PartNumber, MAX(StockPrice) max_price
            FROM    Inventorypart
            GROUP   BY PartNumber
        ) b ON  a.partNumber = b.PartNumber AND
                a.StockPrice = b.max_price
```

for better performance, add an `INDEX` on columns `(PartNumber, StockPrice)`

```
ALTER TABLE InventoryPart ADD INDEX (PartNumber, StockPrice)
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.PartNumber, a.PartDescription, a.CategoryID, a.StockPrice
FROM    InventoryPart a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PartNumber, CategoryID, MAX(StockPrice) max_price
            FROM    Inventorypart
            GROUP   BY PartNumber, CategoryID
        ) b ON  a.partNumber = b.PartNumber AND
                a.StockPrice = b.max_price AND
                a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE InventoryPart ADD INDEX (PartNumber, StockPrice, CategoryID)
```

Comment: This assumes the StockPrice and the UnitPrice are the same values, but just like my answer nonetheless.  Good job.

Comment: Thank you very much, JW. The reason I chose sgeddes' answer as the 'accepted answer' is because your code assumes StockPrice and UnitPrice as the same values. Other than that, it would have worked just fine for me. Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't think this will work -- grouping by partnumber won't return your  max prices -- see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0b43/2 -- group by categoryId only.  Kind regards.